# Jmeter throwing "SocketException: Connection Reset" error on 200 user load test which cant be found in server logs

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have tried running a load test for 200 users. In the application, there was a third party call which led to a "java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset" error. But, there was no such errors on the server logs.

We found the following errors on the server logs

***PegaCRM-Data-xxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxx will restart in 180000 ms System-Queue-xxxx-xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx encountered an execution error. Restarting after delay. com.pega.pegarules.pub.context.prsecurityexception: Problems encountered when setting the access group for the queue activity***

For the third party call transaction, the error in log read:

***RemoteApplicationException : Soap Request failed ResourceUnavailableException : Soap Request failed***

I am not sure about the root cause of the problem. It would be of a great help to know where to look at either from testing standpoint or at the networking end.